What contradiction does Miles see in Hobie's words?
Hobie breaks the shield that Spot activated then he meets Miles:

Hobie: I'm not a role model. I was briefly a runway model. I hate the
a.m. I hate the P.M. I hate labels. I'm not a hero, because calling
yourself a hero makes you a self-mythologizing narcissistic autocrat.
Come on!
Miles: I thought you hated labels.

What contradiction does Miles see in Hobie's words?

"Only a Sith deals in absolutes."

@Valorum Sith in Star Wars ?

Yes, the irony is that that phrase is an absolute. It's ironic, in the same way that Hobie saying that he's the sort of person who doesn't like labels is itself a form of label.

Miles points out a contradiction in Hobie's statement. Despite Hobie's claim that he "hates labels," he ironically launches into a string of self-descriptions that are, well, labels. He tells us he's "not a role model," mentions his brief stint as a "runway model," declares that he's "not a hero," and even goes so far as to say that anyone who calls themselves a hero is a "self-mythologizing narcissistic autocrat."
The humor in this exchange lies in the contradiction between Hobie's words. By defining himself in these ways, Hobie is essentially applying labels. This contradicts his claim of hating labels.

I suspect that Hobie is entirely aware that what he is saying is self-contradictory.

@Dúthomhas You're probably right. Hobie could be playing with irony intentionally. I'll be editing my post accordingly.
